# apps script parse nested json to sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I´ve been cracking my head for days to find the most elegant way to parse a Json string and write it to google sheets. It derives from a webhook off woocommerce.

I have a Json like the following:

```
"product_variations": [
{
  "id": 47131,
  "on_sale": false,
  "regular_price": 1678,
  "sale_price": 0,
  "sku": "GexKiPe-Linen",
  "quantity": "",
  "stock": null,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "slug": "pa_color",
      "option": "linen"
    },
    {
      "name": "material",
      "slug": "pa_material",
      "option": "permanent"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 47132,
  "on_sale": false,
  "regular_price": 1678,
  "sale_price": 0,
  "sku": "GexKiPe-Heather Beige",
  "quantity": "",
  "stock": null,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "slug": "pa_color",
      "option": "heather-beige"
    },
    {
      "name": "material",
      "slug": "pa_material",
      "option": "permanent"
    }
  ]
}
```

An apps script like the following:

```
    function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
      var res = data.product_variations.map(({id, sku, attributes: [{name, option}]}) => [new Date(),id, sku, name, option]);
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1x5m427kv_viOLm7nsJRl1FR0_-e5tOcK-ItEVw0LdEY').getSheetByName('test');
          sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);

}
```

The results in sheets are:

[image: results]

I would like the results to show like:

[image: expected results]

Here is the spreadsheet: [Parse Json](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x5m427kv_viOLm7nsJRl1FR0_-e5tOcK-ItEVw0LdEY/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this

I tested it with the lines that are commented out.  So I have no idea what will happen with the others.

```
function doPost(e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  //const test = '{ "product_variations": [{ "id": 47131, "on_sale": false, "regular_price": 1678, "sale_price": 0, "sku": "GexKiPe-Linen", "quantity": "", "stock": null, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "slug": "pa_color", "option": "linen" }, { "name": "material", "slug": "pa_material", "option": "permanent" } ]},{ "id": 47132, "on_sale": false, "regular_price": 1678, "sale_price": 0, "sku": "GexKiPe-Heather Beige", "quantity": "", "stock": null, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "slug": "pa_color", "option": "heather-beige" }, { "name": "material", "slug": "pa_material", "option": "permanent" }]}]}';
  //const data = JSON.parse(test);
  var res = data.product_variations.map(obj => [new Date(), obj.id, obj.sku, obj.attributes[0].option, obj.attributes[1].option]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1x5m427kv_viOLm7nsJRl1FR0_-e5tOcK-ItEVw0LdEY').getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  //const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  res.unshift(["DateTime","ID","SKU","color","material"]);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Test Results:

| DateTime | ID | SKU | color | material |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/14/2022 | 47131 | GexKiPe-Linen | linen | permanent |  |
| 8/14/2022 | 47132 | GexKiPe-Heather Beige | heather-beige | permanent |  |

[JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#)

Comment: It would almost work, except that the json "option" item is not always in the same order. So the  `obj.attributes[0].option, obj.attributes[1].option` which will write the first `attributes[0].option` will sometimes be switched according to the json order.

Comment: Is there a way to do a search for the `attribute.name` "color" and "material" in order to write it into the correct column?

Comment: I´m looking along the lines of something like: ´var search = "color";
var res = data.product_variations.filter(function (e) { return e.name == search })[0];
var value = res && res.option;´

Comment: I have it thus so far:`var search = "color"
  var res = data.product_variations.map(obj => [new Date(), obj.id, obj.sku, obj.attributes.filter(function (f) { return f.name == search })[0], obj.attributes[1].option]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1F8pgmiSJV0K66lbFOPsdsd8H_LaIi0CGfrukXhD-Gw3g').getSheetByName('test');
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}`   However, it writes the "color" column like: 8/16/2022 21:37:00 47161 GexKiPe-Heather Beige {option=heather-beige-es, name=color, slug=pa_color} permanent-es

Comment: Where it does filter the "color" column properly, I haven´t been able to parse the attributes.option Json

Comment: `obj.attributes.filter(function (f) { return f.name == search })[0].option`this parsed properly

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code. It works like a charm:

```
    function doPost(e) {

  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

    
var search = "color"
var search2 = "material"
  var res = data.product_variations.map(obj => [new Date(),data.acf.product_id,data.id,data.sku,obj.id,obj.sku,obj.regular_price,obj.attributes.filter(function (f) { return f.name == search })[0].option, obj.attributes.filter(function (f) { return f.name == search2 })[0].option]);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1F8pgmiSJV0K66lbFO343O8H_LaIi0CGfrukXhD-Gw3g').getSheetByName('woo product variations');
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).